# Mi ventana de CTkinter crashea cuando utilizo la función <readLine()> de pyserial

Tags: tkinter, pyserial

Necesito hacer una interfaz para el control y monitoreo de un dispositivo controlado por un Arduino Nano. Para ello, utilizo *customtkinter*, además, para enviar y recibir datos por el puerto serial utilizo la librería *pyserial*.

Al escribir datos en el puerto serial todo funciona de manera correcta, sin embargo, cuando utilizo la función `readLine()` la ventana principal se crashea sin imprimir ningún mensaje de error en la terminal de Python.

He tratado de encontrar el problema en un script más sencillo y no parece haber resultado:

```
    import customtkinter, serial, time
    
    arduino = serial.Serial('COM1', 9600)
    time.sleep(1)
    
    window = customtkinter.CTk()
    
    def readFunction():
        word = arduino.readline()
    
    button = customtkinter.CTkButton(master=window, text="Read", command=readFunction)
    button.pack()
    
    window.mainloop()
```

[[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tu problema probablemente se deba a que la función `readline()` se bloquea hasta que se recibe una línea completa a través del puerto serial. Esto significa que si no hay datos disponibles en el puerto serial en ese momento, la función `readline()` se bloqueará y su programa se detendrá allí hasta que se reciba algo en el puerto serial.

Para solucionar este problema, puede intentar usar la función `serial.Serial.in_waiting` antes de llamar a `readline()`. La función `in_waiting` devuelve el número de bytes en el búfer de entrada del puerto serial que aún no se han leído. Si el valor devuelto es mayor que cero, significa que hay datos disponibles en el puerto serial, por lo que puede llamar a `readline()` de forma segura.

Por ejemplo, puede actualizar su función `readFunction()` de la siguiente manera:

```
def readFunction():
    if arduino.in_waiting > 0:
        word = arduino.readline()
        print(word)
```

De esta manera, `readline()` solo se llama cuando hay datos disponibles en el puerto serial y no se bloqueará su programa. También he agregado una impresión de los datos recibidos en la consola para que pueda verificar si está recibiendo los datos correctamente.

Pruébalo y nos dices si ha surgido efecto esta solución.

Comment: Excelente, me funciono a la primera. Buena explicación, bro.